# ASP.NET Server Tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use:

```
<asp:Label id="lbCatId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VideoId") %>' Visible="true" />
```

I get:

```
<span id="ctl00_mainContent_ucCoverFlow_rptVideos_ctl00_lbCatId">5</span>
```

However when I use:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" href='Play.aspx?VideoId=<%# Eval("VideoId") %>' ID="iThumbnailFileName" CssClass="content" />
```

I get:

```
<img id="ctl00_mainContent_ucCoverFlow_rptVideos_ctl01_iThumbnailFileName" class="content" href="Play.aspx?VideoId=&lt;%# Eval(&quot;VideoId&quot;) %>"
```

I would like to know why C# isn't generating the 'VideoId' like it is in the first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the string of the command you want to execute instead of executing it.

Use :

```
 '<%# "Play.aspx?VideoId=" + Eval("VideoId") %>'
```

Instead of :

```
 'Play.aspx?VideoId=<%# Eval("VideoId") %>'
```

Comment: The overload that takes a format string is also useful for this sort of thing: '<%# Eval("VideoId", "Play.aspx?VideoId={0}") %>'

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `ImageUrl` property instead. The `href` attribute probably doesn't know how to interpret databinding syntax.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='Play.aspx?VideoId=<%# Eval("VideoId") %>' ...>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" href='<%# "Play.aspx?VideoId=" + Eval("VideoId") %>' ID="iThumbnailFileName" CssClass="content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
href='Play.aspx?VideoId=<%# Eval("VideoId") %>'
```

to

```
href='<%# "Play.aspx?VideoId=" + Eval("VideoId") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

'<%# Eval("VideoId","Play.aspx?VideoId={0}") %>'